# Trying to change permanent title tag for all of the pages

Tags: magento-1.9, page-title, title

I'm working on a site and can't find where to change the end of the title of all of the pages. All of the titles get the url of the site and i want to change it to the brand itself, and not the URL.

How can i do it?

Thanks,

Comment: which magento version are you using ?

Comment: Magento ver. 1.9.3.9

Answer (score 0):

To change site title you should navigate to following section in admin and update title field :

> System -> Configuration -> Design -> HTML Head -> Default Title

However if you want to change Home page title then navigation to and search for your home page :

> Cms -> Pages ->  Home

and update title there :

like in attached image below :

[image: CMS home page]